# Recursive function without use of <<- assignment?

Tags: r, recursion

Having a vector x, I need to change it recursively in an inner function. Here My implementation of this where I ma using `<<-` global assignment operator:

```
 outer <- function(){
  x <- rep(1,5)
  inner <- function(i){
    if(i> length(x))return(x)
    x[i] <<- 2  ## don't work with <-
    inner(i+1)
  }
  inner(1)
}
outer()
[1] 2 2 2 2 2
```

My question if there is another/better implementation that avoid the use of  `<<-`? Note that I don't want to replace recursion , but just to ask if there is better/safer design?

Comment: How about `x[i]<-inner(i)` and make sure `inner` returns what you want?  oops - I see that's not quite sufficient if you really want to do something with `x` , as right now it's not returned from `outer`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thanks! Does your `inner` still be a `recursive function`?

Comment: If I run just your `inner` with `x[i]<-2` I successfully get the updated values of `x` in the console environment.  So I think all you need to do is have `outer` return `x` for you.

Comment: `<<-` is frowned upon for many valid reasons, but I think your use of it here is quite ok. I assume your real case is more complex than the example you gave, but could you explain why you are not just using a `for` loop on `i` from `1` to `length(x)`? Is it because `i` will jump around in your real case?

Comment: I don't think recursion is save in R. Sooner or later you will see `Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?`

Comment: @flodel yes my real case is more complicated and the recursion end condition is a random one ( actually I have 2 index i and j and , x is a matrix, and I jump randomly from to choose the direction of the next  cell in x, it is  like a randomized version of depth first search .

Comment: Then maybe a `while` loop instead of a recursion?

Comment: @flodel yes of course , I will avoid recursion in a second attempt. The question if the use of <<- is mandatory here ( and you partially answered in your last comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `x` as a parameter?

```
outer <- function(){
  x <- rep(1,5)
  inner <- function(i,x){
    if(i> length(x))return(x)
    x[i] <- 2  
    inner(i+1,x)
  }
  inner(1,x)
}
outer()
#[1] 2 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: @Roland thanks, but actually my real x is a big matrix so copying many times ( the recursion depth) will drop performance, isn'it?

Comment: I would look very hard for possibilities to avoid recursion in R.