# Determine emptiness in R without having to use length()

Tags: r, recursion, string

Currently, this is more of a thought experiment.

So, I'm trying to write a recursive function, very basic:

```
omnom <-function( a.vector, n ){
    if( SOME.FUN( a.vector ){
        n <-n +1
        omnom( a.vector[-1], n)
    }

return( n )
}
```

The function `omnom` takes a vector and a count variable and returns the number of elements in the vector i.e., `omnom()` does the same thing as `length()`. It does this recursively by checking some condition - if it's `TRUE` the function will add `1` to 'n' and call itself with a reduced vector and the current state of `n`.

My question: What could I use for `SOME.FUN()`? I tried `is.null()` but if `omnom()` has gobbled up all elements, `a.vector` will be `integer(0)` - which is not `NULL`. `a.vector` will be empty but I don't know any function which checks for emptiness. Similarly, `integer(0) ==FALSE` will return `logical(0)` - which is, by the way, not `FALSE`, just like `integer(0) ==TRUE`.

Edit: The type of data, I'm trying to process is something along the lines of:

```
a.vector <-c( "bla", 1010, "yadayadayada")
```

Of course, I could use `length(a.vector) ==0` but that would be kind of pointless. Then again, the whole purpose of the function might seem pointless. I'm trying to see what works and now that I did, I'm wondering if or why there is no function which checks for emptiness. Also, since I'm no programmer, I have no clue how I would even go about checking for emptiness.

Comment: `nzchar` checks for emptiness.  It looks for non-zero length character strings.  For example, `nzchar("lalala")` returns `TRUE` while `nzchar("")` is `FALSE`.

Comment: Hey, I didn't know that one. Still, it also doesn't return 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'. It returns 'logical(0)' which results in an error message because 'nzchar()' is only used for characters and it returns the number of elements in a character string. The error message denounces the argument list of length 0 that I used for 'if()'. So, this will not work for numeric vectors.

Comment: try `nzchar(as.character(10))`

Comment: Still, it also doesn't help since I'm trying to count the number of elements in a vector, not in a character string. Of course the vector might consist of character strings but `nzchar()` returns `logical(0)` if I do `character(0)` as well.

Comment: One major problem here is that you cannot nest the function `omnom` that you haven't defined yet inside the same function that isn't yet defined.

Comment: Also, `c( "bla", 1010, list(), "yadayadayada", data.frame( a =1, b =2 ))` is not a vector, it's a list.

Comment: Okay, you're right. My bad. It's a list. Nevertheless, recursive functions do work. And this one does work if I do `if( length( a.vector !=0 ){ ... }`. I will do something about the list thing.

Comment: @RichardScriven See here for example: http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/5931/Recurse/recurse.html
or here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118670/recursive-function-without-use-of-assignment?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This may help.  I took out the nested call to `omnom` so you can see what's happening.  We can get around the `character(0)` by using `paste` or `paste0`

```
> nzchar(paste0(character(0), collapse = ""))
[1] FALSE

> omnom <-function( a.vector, n ){
      if( nzchar(paste0(a.vector, collapse = "")) ){ n <- n +1 }            
      return(n)
  }
> omnom(1:10, n = 3)
[1] 4
> omnom(NA, n = 3)
[1] 4
> omnom(character(0), n = 3)
[1] 3
> vec <-c( "bla", 1010, list(), "yadayadayada", data.frame( a =1, b =2 ))
> omnom(vec, n = 3)
[1] 4
```

Comment: Looks like a nice hack, I'm out of time now, I'll have a look later on.